# Retrieve a row using a function similar to like

Tags: hbase

In case I have a row as `12345^abc^xyz` in `Hbase`, is it possible to retrieve all the rows containing abc ?

Example :

```
Row 1 :789^abc^www
Row 2 :890^abc^yyy
Row 3 :800^abc^xxx
```

I need to retrieve all rows which contain the String abc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **RowFilter** with **SubstringComparator** to achieve that. Something like this :

> Filter filter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new
>   SubstringComparator("abc"));

You might also find **FuzzyRowFilter** useful. It's new, but really effective. See [this](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.html) for more details.

HTH

Comment: This worked for me when i was trying in Java. But i tried to do the following in Hbase shell, scan 'test', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.RowFilter.new(CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),SubstringComparator.new("abc\^cde\^efg.*"))} , where my actual row is "abc^cde^efghijk". This doesnt return me any result